# Check if user is signed in and valid using Amplify Cognito

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin, authentication, amazon-cognito

I'm developing an app where users can create an account and sign in to their profiles. When they close the app and relaunch it, they should automatically be signed in. Currently, I am implementing it as follows:

```
fun isSignedIn(): Boolean {
    return Amplify.Auth.currentUser != null
}

if (isSignedIn()) {
    // main app
} else {
    // auth screen
}
```

However, there is a functionality available on the AWS Cognito website where you can select a user and sign them out or deactivate their account, essentially banning that user.

But when I launch the app, `Amplify.Auth.currentUser` still doesn't return null, as it appears to cache the user's session.

My question is: how can I check if the user is signed in and determine if the user has been banned or not? Do I need to initiate the sign-in process in the background each time the app opens and save the username and password the first time the user signs in?

Since I am new to Cognito and AWS in general, I'm unsure about the best approach to tackle this issue. I've been trying to find solutions on forums, but I haven't found an answer yet.